# smallest eigenvalue when dot product with a fixed vector is real

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Consider $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and for the sake of simplicity assume that its Euclidean norm is one. If we want to project a vector $y\in\mathbb{C}^n$ onto the following space
\begin{equation*}
\{z\in\mathbb{C}^n\quad\text{such that}\quad x^*z=0\}.
\end{equation*}
This is easy the answer is just $(I-xx^*)y$. What is the answer for projection on to the following space
\begin{equation*}
\{z\in\mathbb{C}^n\quad\text{such that}\quad x^*z\quad\text{is real}\}.
\end{equation*}
Perhaps there is a formula for it if we concatenate $x$ and its element-wise conjugate $\bar{x}$ as a vector in $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$?

Since I got a negative vote at the start Let me explain things further. Assume $Y$ and $R$ are two matrices and use $\bar{Y}$ and $\bar{R}$ to denote element-wise conjugation. I'm interested in understanding the minimum value of 
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}y\\ \bar{y}\end{bmatrix}^*\begin{bmatrix}Y & R\\ \bar{R} & \bar{Y}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y\\ \bar{y}\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
subject to the Euclidean norm of $y$ is one and $x^*y$ is real for a fixed vector $x$. the motivation behind the above question is to understand if I can change the problem above into an eigenvalue problem of a modified matrix.

Comment: Since you are talking about complex vector spaces, it is worth while to point out that the relation $x^* z\in\Bbb R$ for $z\in\Bbb C^n$ does not define a subspace.